# How to refresh CVCalendar when I get data from the server?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I am using CVCalendar to display calendar with events. But the events are loading from the rest api call . I cant update the the events in the calendar after getting response.
Hope to get help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call

```
calendarView.contentController.refreshPresentedMonth()
```

after datasource was changed

Comment: this refreshes only the current month, but the previous month doesn't get reloaded. how can we fix that